# Should a select box be populated from my app's test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing my first Rails app and this problem has stumped me for a few days. I'm using Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial as a guide and thus am using RSpec and Capybara to write tests.

I have created models for a Rink object and a Rating object. Users are supposed to be able to create a Rating for a Rink. I have written a test that checks whether a Rating is created when the user inputs valid information to create a rating. Part of creating a valid Rating is selecting which Rink a Rating is connected to via a select box. The select box is populated with Rinks from the database.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "RatingPages" do

subject { page }

describe "rating creation" do
    before { visit new_rating_path }

    let(:submit) { "Rate it!" }

    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:rink) { FactoryGirl.create(:rink) }

        before do
            select("Victoria Park", :from => 'rating[rink_id]')
            fill_in "ice",  with: "4"
            fill_in "players",      with: "10"
            fill_in "comment",      with: "Great ice!" 
        end

        it "should create a rating" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(Rating, :count).by(1)
        end

    end
end
end
```

Because creating a Rating is dependent on the existence of a Rink, my test uses FactoryGirl to create a Rink in the test database.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :rink do
    name        "Victoria Park"
    address     "516 King Street West"
end
```

When I run this test I get an error that says Capybara cannot find the Rink created in my test.

> 2) RatingPages rating creation with valid information should create a user
>        Failure/Error: select("Victoria Park", :from => 'rating[rink_id]')
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find option "Victoria Park"
>        # ./spec/requests/rating_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in '

Here is what I have tried so far: I created a Rink manually in the development database using the console and got the test to pass. I have also confirmed that my factory is successfully creating a Rink.

So the problem, I think, is that the select box is drawing from the development database and not the test database when I run the test. Thus, the Rink I create using the factory is showing up in the test database but not in the select box as one of the options.

I think there is a pretty good possibility that I am going about writing this test the wrong way but I have not been able to find any help from Google searches. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

EDIT - Here is the view code that generates the select box:

```
<% provide(:title, "New Rating") %>

<h1>Post a new rating</h1>

<%= form_for(@rating) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<%= f.label "Select a rink:" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:rink_id, Rink.all, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a rink') %>

<%= f.label "Rate the ice quality." %>
<%= f.select :ice, [['Great!', 4], ['Fair', 3], ['Poor', 2], ['Unskateable', 1]] %>

<%= f.label "How many people are playing hockey?" %>
<%= f.text_field :players %>

<%= f.label :comment %>
<%= f.text_area :comment%>

<%= f.submit "Rate it!" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use:

```
let(:rink) { FactoryGirl.create(:rink) }
```

it wont actually create the Rink model until you call `rink` during your test. Since you're not calling `rink`, the model never gets created.

If you change it to:

```
let!(:rink) { FactoryGirl.create(:rink) }
```

(notice the bang after `let!`), it will create the model immediately and be available in your form.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I tried this as per your suggestion but I am still getting the error 'Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find option'. Do you have any other ideas? My other tests that draw from the test database are working fine so maybe it is something about the select box.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the view code that generates the select box within the form?

Comment: Move `visit new_rating_path` into the same before block where you select the Victoria Park rink. Add it right before the call to `select`. What's happening is that Capybara is visiting the page prior to the `let!` call that actually creates the rink, so when Capybara loads the page, there are not any rinks in the database.

Comment: That worked! Your explanation makes sense too. I don't know enough about Capybara yet to spot that kind of thing but I understand now that you have pointed it out to me. Thanks again for your help.